# iPad - Show vertical Pagination

Tags: iphone, ios, scrollview

In My iPad vertical scroll view each subview is of screen size. So at a time one view is shown.

I want to represent how many views or pages are there in the scrollview to scroll. this is some how i want to show as pagination.

Please help me how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `UIPageControl`. Or just write page 1/x on each page.

Edit: to get the page count calculate this:
`scrollView.contentSize.height / scrollView.frame.size.height`.